# Calculated column or measure depending on parameter

Tags: powerbi

First of all: This is a crosspost of my question at the [powerbi-community forum](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Calculated-column-or-measure-depending-on-parameter/m-p/3483189)

I have a fairly simple problem, but I'm not really able to solve it.

Let's say I have the following data, *Table1.* With an *ID* column and an *err* column:

| ID | err |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.51 |
| 2 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 0.24 |
| 4 | 0.65 |
| 5 | 0.27 |
| 6 | 0.73 |
| 7 | 0.51 |
| 8 | 0.34 |
| 9 | 0.16 |
| 10 | 0.93 |

Now I want to use a decimal parameter *tolerance*, that can be set using a slider.

Depending on the value of *tolerance*, I want to classify the Errors from *Table1* into faulty (1) or non-faulty (0) parts and visualize the relative proportions of faulty vs non-faulty in a pie chart.

Conceptionally I just need a calculated column like:

```
faulty = Table1[err] > tol[tol value]
```

But a calculated column does not update dynamically if the user changes the tolerance value with the slider.

A measure on the other hand does not allow me to use the values from *Table1* without aggregation. (I don't really understand the reason?)

I couldn't really believe that it's not possible to solve such a trivial task in PowerBi.

So here I am asking for your help :slightly_smiling_face:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need a disconnected table with all the possible tolerances, sometimes called a [Parameter table](https://www.sqlbi.com/p/dax-patterns-parameter-table/), and then use that in a measure using [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function).

You must aggregate in a measure because it's possible, but not required, that the measure is evaluated in a filter scope that contains multiple rows.  But if you put that measure on a visual with one ID per row, you'll get the value you want.

Comment: Thank you! I kind of managed to achieve what I was trying to do with a measure and a Parameter
`ok = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1; Table1[err] <= Parameter[Parameter Value]))`

BUT the big drawback here for me is that I am not able to retrieve the underlying data anymore by right-clicking on the visualization and selecting show as table.
This will only result in the aggregated table.